# Gram Schmidt inner and outer products

Tags: equation-solving, programming, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, linear-algebra

I know the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization generates an orthonormal basis from an arbitrary basis. I need help with:

> **Write a program that inputs a list $\{b_1,\dotsc,b_n\}$ of linearly independent vectors and an inner proudct and outputs a list of orthonormal vectors $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ with the same span.**

```
            innerproduct1[f_,g_]:=Sum[(f/.t->i)(g/.t->i), {i,1,4}]

            gramschmidt2[innerproduct1_,list2_]:=
              Module[{k,u,v,e},
               k=Length[list2];
               Do[Subscript[v,i]=list2[[i]],{i,1,k}];
               Do[Subscript[u,i]=
                 Subscript[v,i]-
                  Sum[(innerproduct1[Subscript[v,i],Subscript[u,j]]/
                      innerproduct1[Subscript[u,j], Subscript[u,j]]*Subscript[u,j],  {j,1 ,i-1}];
              Subscript[e,i]=
               Subscript[u,i]/Sqrt[innerproduct1[Subscript[u,i].Subscript[u,i]]],{i, 1,k}];
            Table[Subscript[e,i],{i,1,k}]
            ]
```

Sorry if the program is wrong. I might be going ahead of what I read which I probably am.

I just learned somethings about the Gram-Schmidt process from reading an analysis text a couple days ago. I saw this question online and thought I would try to solve it with what I read. I came to some frustration and really wanted to know how to write a *Mathematica* program for this.

Comment: What is the issue with the program you wrote?

Comment: I just fixed my program. I think this is what the question in bold is asking. Can someone please tell me if this is correct? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did you check the Mathematica document about 'Orthogonalize' command. There you can specify method as Gram-Schmidt. If you check the "Applications" part you can also find a related example for linearly independent vectors, the result is a set orthonormal with the given inner product.

Comment: It looks almost correct though I won't say I tested in any great detail. One issue I can see is use of a dot in the last call made to innerproduct1. I suspect a comma was wanted there.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Is it ok if you can show me your written program. I tried this for a couple days now and would like to compare this to someone who knows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in command for orthogonalizing vectors by generating a Gram-Schmidt basis (as suggested by s.s.o in a comment). Say you have some linearly independent vectors (generated here using `RandomReal`). For example, this generates three 10-D vectors at random.

```
z = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 10}]

orthoZ = Orthogonalize[z]
```

gives the three vectors in orthonormal form, as you can check:

```
orthoZ.Transpose[orthoZ] // Chop
{{1., 0, 0}, {0, 1., 0}, {0, 0, 1.}}
```

You can also specify your own inner product using the optional second argument of `Orthogonalize`. For example:

```
Orthogonalize[{1, x, x^2, x^3}, Integrate[Times[##], {x, -1, 1}] &]
```

uses $<x,y>=\int x(t) y(t) dt$ as the inner product and orthogonalizes the first few polynomials.